# Hibernate Creating an already created table even if property <name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"> is set to update.(Db is postgres)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Hibernate as an ORM for a Spring Boot Application to write values to my Postgres Database.I have configured the properties in my persistence.xml

Persistence.xml

```
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ImageHoster" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres" />

    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
</properties>
```

I have created an entity called Movie

Movie

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Movie")
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public String id;

    @Column(name = "movie")
    public String movie;

    @Column(name = "updatedDate")
    public Date updatedDate;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "image")
    public String image;

    public String getMovie() {
        return movie;
    }

    public void setMovie(String movie) {
        this.movie = movie;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedDate() {
        return updatedDate;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDate(Date updatedDate) {
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

At the first time when there is no movie table in my postgres database the table is getting created and there is no error.But as i am running the application once the table is created it is trying to create the table again which is causing the below error

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement.

My Configuration for the JPA goes like this

JPAConfig

```
@Configuration
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf =new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml");
        emf.afterPropertiesSet();

        return emf.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ImageHoster");
        ds.setUsername("postgres");
        ds.setPassword("postgres");

        return ds;
    }
}
```

**Any idea where i am going wrong as I have another entity called User which is working fine and is not getting created everytime the application runs.**

Comment: As a side note, change `public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory()` to `public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()`. Don't create the `EntityManagerFactory` yourself using `.getObject()` - `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` is a `DisposableBean`, and by not making it a bean proper, you're not letting Spring clean after it

Answer (score 0):

Once i changed the table name from Movie to movie in my entity everything was working as expected.

@Entity
@Table(name = "movie"){

}

This made everything fine..any idea why this happened? as i am not able to understand why it is a problem.